# Struggling to apply chain rule on a recursive function

Tags: recurrence-relations, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I have that $h_{t}(w)=f(h_{t-1}(w),w)$ and $h_{1}(w)=f(w)$ and I'm trying to find $y = \frac{\partial h_{t}}{\partial w}$

My attempt so far

$\frac{\partial h_{t}}{\partial w} = \sum_{i=1}^{t} \frac{\partial h_{t}}{\partial h_{i}} * \frac{\partial h_{i}}{\partial w}$

But it doesn't feel right. In particular, it's as if each second term in the sum will correspond to its own sum.

To reach what I did, I used the fact that $h_t$ is a function of all $h_i$ for $1<=i<=t-1$ with each (including $h_{t}$) being a function in $w$

Comment: Let's be clear: do you mean $h_t(w)=f(h_{t-1}(w),w)$ ?

Comment: Yes, I thought that was implicitly implied. Will modify the question.

Comment: Well you haven't modified it: it is $h_t(w)$ and $h_1(w)$ on the LHS. It matters.

Comment: And now we have a second difficulty. You are using $f$ both as the name of a unary function when you write $h_1(w)=f(w)$ and then as the name of a binary function when you write $h_t(w)=f(h_{t-1}(w),w)$. These can't be the same function, so please re-edit to tell us what you mean.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the corrections. How should I express it in case it's true that $h_{1}(w)=f(h_{0},w)$ but $h_{0}$ is constant?

Comment: Just use the $h_t(w)=f(...$ formula for $t\geqslant 1$ and let $h_0(w)=c$ where $c$ is a constant.  However I have worked out a few terms and can't spot a pattern: there are going to be a lot of products involved.

Answer (score 1):

From  the comments I wonder if this is what you are asking.

Suppose we are given some $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and some  function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, all of whose derivatives exist.
Then we can define recursively a sequence of
functions (of a single variable) $h_t:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by

$$
h_t(w)=
\begin{cases}
c &\text{ when $t=0$;}\\
f(h_{t-1}(w),w) &\text{ when $t\geqslant 1$.} 
\end{cases}
$$

Find an expression for $h_t'(w)$.

Notation: Let us write $f_1(x,y)$ for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$, and $f_2(x,y)$ for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)$.

The derivatives of the first few $h_t$ are as follows.

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
h_0'(w) &=& 0;\\
h_1'(w) &=& f_2(h_0(w),w);\\
h_2'(w) &=& f_1(h_1(w),w)f_2(h_0(w),w)+f_2(h_1(w),w);\\
h_3'(w) &=& f_1(h_2(w),w)f_1(h_1(w),w)f_2(h_0(w),w)+f_1(h_2(w),w)f_2(h_1(w),w)+f_2(h_2(w),w).
\end{eqnarray}
$$

I think it's clear what the pattern is, and that it would be straightforward to prove by induction. But it would be a notational nightmare and perhaps not very illuminating.

*If there is an easier answer to this question I hope someone will post it and then I can delete this very extended comment.*